# Is there something like JavaScript hoisting in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am wondering if variables and methods can be used before declaration in Ruby. Is there something like hoisting in JavaScript?

```
def calcArea
  getWidth * getHeight
end

def getWidth
  @w
end
def getHeight
  @h
end
@w = 10
@h = 20

p calcArea
```

Comment: Defining methods and instance variables in Ruby's top-level blurs the variable scope. It might be cleaner to wrap everything in a proper class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I am wondering if variables and methods can be used before declaration in Ruby.

Variables don't need to be declared in Ruby, so that part of the question doesn't make sense. Variables come into existence when they are first assigned, or, in the case of local variables, when their first assignment is *parsed*.

Methods are *defined*, not declared. A method definition is a piece of code just like any other piece of code. It needs to be executed to take effect. You cannot call a method that doesn't exist, and a method only exists after its definition has executed.

> Is there something like hoisting in JavaScript?

No.

> ```
> def calcArea
>   getWidth * getHeight
> end
>
> def getWidth
>   @w
> end
> def getHeight
>   @h
> end
> @w = 10
> @h = 20
>
> p calcArea
> ```

This works just fine, but it has nothing to do with hoisting. You only call `calcArea` after it has been defined, so that's perfectly okay. `calcArea` calls `getWidth` and `getHeight`, but only when `calcArea` itself gets called, which is after *all* methods have been defined, so that's okay. `getWidth` and `getHeight` access `@w` and `@h`, but again, at the point that `getWidth` and `getHeight` are called, `@w` and `@h` have already been assigned, so that's okay, too. (And even if they *hadn't* been assigned, accessing them is still not an error, accessing an non-existent instance variable just evaluates to `nil`; obviously, you would then get a `NoMethodError` for trying to call `*` on `nil`, but that's very different from getting a `NameError` for a non-existent variable.)

Some notes on coding style:

- Ruby uses `snake_case` for methods, parameters, local variables, instance variables, class variables, and global variables.
- Ruby doesn't use a `get` prefix for getters.
- Trivial getters should be named the same as the instance variable.
- Also, `calcArea` is basically a getter for the area, so it, too, should be named without a prefix.
- There should be a blank line after a method definition.

So, according to Ruby community style, your code should look like this:

```
def area
  width * height
end

def width
  @width
end

def height
  @height
end

@width  = 10
@height = 20

p area
```

If this were part of a module or class definition, then you could use `attr_reader` to auto-generate the getters, and `attr_writer` to generate setters:

```
class Rectangle
  attr_reader :width, :height

  def area
    width * height
  end

  private

  attr_writer :width, :height

  def initialize(width, height)
    self.width, self.height = width, height
  end
end

rect = Rectangle.new(10, 20)

p rect.area
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation in detail. This makes clarify my concept.

Answer (score 3):

Your example works just fine in Ruby.

In JavaScript, hoisting means that Javascript moves your variable declarations to the top of the current scope. According to this [article](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/c0c0dd4ef8-variable-hoisting-in-ruby), Ruby also does some sort of hoisting. However, it's debatable if it's in the same sense as the Javascript counterpart (see comments).

Another reason your example probably should work is that the variables `@w` and `@h` are `nil` unless not defined, and since you *have* defined them before calling `calcArea`, they have their actual values.

Comment: I do not think this is true. Replace the `binding.pry` invocation with a simple print and you will get an error.

Comment: Maybe it's a feature of `pry`? I don't know, I didn't write the article in question - just something I found. Now that you mention it, it *does* seem weird that Ruby would have hoisting.

Comment: Found another article that supports the presence of hoisting: http://ieftimov.com/variable-hoisting-ruby

"Basically, when the parser runs over the if-clause (look in weird_3.rb example file) it first declares the variable, regardless of whether it will actually be executed."

Comment: True, but I wouldn't call this hoisting (not in the JS sense). Firstly, this doesn't happen method wide. Secondly, you have to pass the code where the variable is declared (even if it didn't actually get executed) to have it assigned `nil`.

Comment: A local variable (with an initial value of `nil`) is created once the parser encounters an assignment (anywhere in the current scope). But its name refers to the local variable only after the assignment. Prior to the assignment, it may refer to either a local variable or a method.

Comment: Edited the post to refer to the comments.